# How to deploy pinax with virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, pinax

I developed one application with Pinax http://pinaxproject.com/. I created project by  `pinax-admin setup_project mysite -b social` in my local virtualenv, i want to deploy my project to my Centos server, so how to setup the libraries ? you know i setup many libraries by `pinax-admin setup_project mysite -b social` and all libraries are installed into my local virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you create a new virtualenv on your server and install your dependencies into it. The documentation recommends `zc.buildout`: http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/buildout/.